Using Webworkers for both parallel rendering and data generation in Chartjs
I am changing from Dygraph to Chartjs because of rendering webworkers and wish to fully multithread the graph to keep main thread empty as much as possible. I am trying to use Workers for handling data and rendering as mentioned on the Chart.js page:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/performance/. I have problems at reusing the canvas and implementing the parallel rendering.
I am able to use Webworkers for the data but unable to get it to draw due to
Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart' can be reused.



<template>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</template>


<script>
  testGraph() {

  let data = [];
  const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));

  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    data = e.data;
// Add new data to the existing dataset
    console.log(data);
    myChart.update();  // Update the chart with new data
  };

  // Set up the chart
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'TestLabel',
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      animation: false,
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'bottom'
        },
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });


  setInterval(() => {
    worker.postMessage('start');
  }, 5000);
},

</script>

Worker.js code bellow
function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }

self.onmessage = function() {
    var data = [];
        for (let j=0;j < 10; j++) {
            data.push({ x: j, y: getRandomInt(1000) });
        }
        postMessage(data);
};




This code now works data gets transfered by the worker the issue now is if i dont destroy the chart constantly it refuses to be drawn (Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart' can be reused.) still figuring the canvas webworker out.


    testGraph() {
      let data = [];
      // reseta chart konstantno ne dela brez.
      if (myChart) {
        myChart.destroy();
      }

      const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));

      worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        data = e.data;

        myChart.data.datasets[0].data = data;
        myChart.update();  // ponovno nariše graf
        };

      const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
      myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            label: 'TestLabel',
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          animation: false,
          scales: {
            x: {
              type: 'linear',
              position: 'bottom'
            },
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        }
      });
        worker.postMessage('start');
    }
///this is worker.js file
    function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      }

    self.onmessage = function() {
        var data = [];
            for (let j=0;j < 1000; j++) {
                data.push({ x: j, y: getRandomInt(1000) });
            }
            postMessage(data);
    };
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.13/vue.global.min.js"></script>
    <template>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </template>




Realistically i have to create a New component for the graph itself to fix the canvas in use error but as of right now i am testing it in Legacy code so that i can retain data from signals (32000 samples/s)
